# MS Access & MS query in excel giving different output

Tags: excel, ms-access-2010, ms-query

I have a database that has been done in Microsoft Access which joins together 5 tables. I am trying to replicate this in Excel using MS Query. I have gone onto the design view for the query in Access and then copied this in MS query. The tables are exactly the same as well. I am getting different results from the queries ran in MS Access and MS query though. Is there anything that I have obviously missed? Any ideas what I am doing wrong? This is for office 2010.

Comment: show your sql, your connection string, your sample data from both

Comment: I didn't use any sql, just the visual tool where you link up the tables

Comment: You can "View SQL"